# How Can I Version Multiple Maven Projects?

Tags: maven

I have a *set* of Spring Boot-based microservice projects.  Each is a multi-module project, with a root POM, and module directories with their own POMs.  Each root POM has, as it's parent, the `spring-boot-starter-parent` artifact.

Each of these multi-module projects currently build successfully, and result in 3 artifacts each.  However, each project has it's own version.

I want to accomplish 2 things:

1. Stamp this *set* of microservice projects with a common version across
   all of them.
2. Enforce a common set of dependency versions across all
   of them, similar to how `<dependencyManagement>` works within a project. (*e.g.*  force each service to use version `x.y.z` of the
   `example-common-dependency` dependency)

Is this possible in Maven?

If not, what about Gradle?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you want the same version for all your microservices, couldn't you just build them in _one_ multi-module project?

Comment: Yes, I thought about doing that.  However, these services were developed independently, and have independent build/deploy processes already in place.  Re-arranging them all into a single multi-module project seemed like more effort than I wanted to take on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways you can accomplish both #1 and #2 using maven. Check out the maven docs on POMs: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html. There are pros and cons to each type of setup. The "Project Inheritance" could do much, if not all, of #1 and #2 for you. That might be a simple way to start. You may also want to look at using spring boot without the spring boot parent: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent. This could give you more flexibility b/c a maven project cannot have multiple parents. Hope this helps.

Comment: I was able to create a multi-project hierarchy where a BOM "parent" project had, as its children, the root POM of the individual projects - essentially replicating the multi-module project pattern at a project level.  Thanks!